# startActivityForResult in a file uploader showing error after migrating to androix in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, androidx

```
//File manager
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(
                WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback,
                FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
            if (mUMA != null) {
                mUMA.onReceiveValue(null);
            }
            mUMA = filePathCallback;
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(WebviewActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null) {
                File photoFile = null;
                try {
                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCM);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Image file creation failed", ex);
                }
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    mCM = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                } else {
                    takePictureIntent = null;
                }
            }
            Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            contentSelectionIntent.setType("*/*");
            Intent[] intentArray;
            if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
            } else {
                intentArray = new Intent[0];
            }
            Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FCR);
            return true;
        }
```

Here is the code of the file uploading from webviewactivity.java in my android app. after I have updated my app to androidX in android studio. It's showing me an error that startActivityForResult() is deprecated function and I have to use registerForActivityResult() instead. I have fixed all the issues created after upgrading to androidX. May be as I am a junior android developer I can not understand how do I fix this issue I have also checked developer.android.com documention for registerForActivityResult() function but I can't understand How I can use that here and fix the issue as showing is android studio.

A kind help from any senior is appricated. I have also compiled the app by ignoring this said issue showing in android studio that's compiled and working in my Smartphone having API level 24 not sure is File Upload will work on API level 29, 30, 31 phones. for your further information I can't use and Virtual Device since my Laptop is Resource is too low to work with AVD.

Thanks.

Comment: Where are/were you using startActivityForResult to upload a file?

Comment: `Here is the code of the file uploading from webviewactivity.java in my android app` Dont think so. That code has nothing to do with uploading of a file. Only with selecting a file. Or taking a picture.

Comment: `It's showing me an error that startActivityForResult() is deprecated` That is no error but a warning. All will just work as allways. `and I have to use registerForActivityResult() instead. ` No. That is an advise only.

Comment: `takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));` You cannot use Uri.fromFile() here since Andord N/24. Instead you should use a FileProvider.

Answer (score 0):

```
ActivityResultLauncher<String> mGetContent;//declare
```

initialize `mGetContent` by calling below function

```
private void initializePicker(){
    mGetContent =
            registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(),
                    uri -> {
                        if(uri!=null) {
                            noticeUri = uri;
                            //do your work here or
                            //save the uri in global variable for future use
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(CROption.this, "No file selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
}
```

start picker using below line:

```
mGetContent.launch("application/pdf")//allow to select only pdf files
```